# OpenGL - Project shadow cubemap onto scene

Tags: opengl, matrix, shadow

I've successfully rendered my scene from my light's point of view onto a depth cubemap, but I don't quite understand how I can actually project it onto my scene.

Here's a short clip of the current situation: http://youtu.be/54WXDWxqmXw

I found an implementation example on how to do it over here:

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/174093-GLSL-cube-shadows-projecting?p=1219162&viewfull=1#post1219162

It seemed fairly easy to understand, so I figured this would be a great way to start off with, but I'm having some difficulties with the matrices (As shown in the video above).

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(std140) uniform ViewProjection
{
    mat4 V;
    mat4 P;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;
out vec4 posCs;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 lightView;

void main()
{
    mat4 MVP = P *V *M;
    gl_Position = MVP *vec4(vertexPosition,1);

    UV = vertexUV;
    posCs = V *M *vec4(vertexPosition,1);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV;
in vec4 posCs;

out vec4 color;

// Diffuse texture
uniform sampler2D renderTexture;

uniform samplerCubeShadow shadowCubeMap;

uniform mat4 lightView;
uniform mat4 lightProjection;
uniform mat4 camViewInv;

void main()
{
    color = texture2D(renderTexture,UV).rgba;

    mat4 lView = mat4(1); // The light is currently at the world origin, so we'll skip the transformation for now (The less potential error sources the better)
    vec4 posLs = lView *camViewInv *posCs;
    vec4 posAbs = abs(posLs);
    float fs_z = -max(posAbs.x,max(posAbs.y,posAbs.z));
    vec4 clip = lightProjection *vec4(0.0,0.0,fs_z,1.0);
    float depth = (clip.z /clip.w) *0.5 +0.5;
    vec4 r = shadowCube(shadowCubeMap,vec4(posLs.xyz,depth));
    color *= r;
}
```

(I've only posted the relevant parts)

lightProjection is the same projection matrix that I've used to render the scene into the cubemap.

I'm not entirely sure about 'camViewInv', from the example I've linked above I came up with this:

```
glm::mat4 camViewInv(
    camView[0][0],camView[1][0],camView[2][0],0.0f,
    camView[0][1],camView[1][1],camView[2][1],0.0f,
    camView[0][2],camView[1][2],camView[2][2],0.0f,
    camPos[0],camPos[1],camPos[2],1.0f
);
```

camView being the camera's view matrix, and camPos the camera's worldspace position.

Everything else should be self-explanatory I believe.

I can't see anything wrong with the shaders, but I'm fairly certain the scene is rendered correctly to the cubemap (As shown in the video above). Maybe someone more versed than me can spot the issue.

// Update:

Some additional information about the creation / usage of the shadow cubemap:

Creating the cubemap texture:

```
unsigned int frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);

unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1,&texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC,GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE,GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X +i,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,size,size,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X +i,texture,0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
}
```

The light's matrices:

```
glm::perspective<float>(90.f,1.f,2.f,m_distance); // Projection Matrix

// View Matrices
glm::vec3 pos = GetPosition(); // Light worldspace position
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(1,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(-1,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(0,1,0),glm::vec3(0,0,-1))
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(0,-1,0),glm::vec3(0,0,1))
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(0,0,1),glm::vec3(0,1,0))
glm::lookAt(pos,pos +glm::vec3(0,0,-1),glm::vec3(0,1,0))
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexPosition;

uniform mat4 shadowMVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = shadowMVP *vertexPosition;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out float fragmentDepth;

void main()
{
    fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest doing this in world space, light positions are typically defined in world space and it will reduce the workload if you keep it that way. I removed a bunch of uniforms that you do not need if you do this in world space.

#### Compute lighting direction and depth in vtx. shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout(std140) uniform ViewProjection
{
    mat4 V;
    mat4 P;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexPosition; // W is automatically assigned 1, if missing.
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 UV;
out vec4 lightDirDepth; // Direction = xyz, Depth = w

uniform mat4 M;

uniform vec3 lightPos;     // World Space Light Pos
uniform vec2 shadowZRange; // Near / Far clip plane distances for shadow's camera

float vecToDepth (vec3 Vec)
{
  vec3  AbsVec     = abs (Vec);
  float LocalZcomp = max (AbsVec.x, max (AbsVec.y, AbsVec.z));

  const float n = shadowZRange [0]; // Near plane when the shadow map was built
  const float f = shadowZRange [1]; // Far plane when the shadow map was built

  float NormZComp = (f+n) / (f-n) - (2.0*f*n)/(f-n)/LocalZcomp;
  return (NormZComp + 1.0) * 0.5;
}

void main()
{
    mat4 MVP = P *V *M;
    gl_Position = MVP *vertexPosition;

    UV    = vertexUV;

    vec3  lightDir   = lightPos - (M *vertexPosition).xyz;
    float lightDepth = vecToDepth (lightDir);

    lightDirDepth = vec4 (lightDir, lightDepth);
}
```

#### Modified Fragment Shader (sample cubemap using light dir, and test against depth):

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV;
in vec4 lightDirDepth;  // Direction = xyz, Depth = w

out vec4 color;

// Diffuse texture
uniform sampler2D         renderTexture;
uniform samplerCubeShadow shadowCubeMap;

void main()
{
    const float bias = 0.0001; // Prevent shadow acne

    color   = texture (renderTexture,UV).rgba;   
    float r = texture (shadowCubeMap, vec4 (lightDirDepth.xyz, lightDirDepth.w + bias));

    color *= r;
}
```

#### I added two new uniforms:

1. `lightPos` -- World space position of your light
2. `shadowZRange` -- The values of your near and far plane when you built your shadow cube map, packed into a `vec2`

Let me know if you need me to explain anything or if this does not produce meaningful results.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. The z-component of lightDir was inverted, but including the light's projection matrix fixed that: vec3 lightDir = lightPos -(lightProjection *M *vertexPosition).xyz;. It does, however, always project it in one direction only (Regardless of the change above): http://youtu.be/a8tQn2pvB_w

Comment: That is using the shaders I wrote? You do not want to use the projection matrix if you do this in world space, that was the point of re-writing it. Are you sure the light position is in world space?

Comment: I think you are going to need to show the code you used to build the cube map in order to diagnose this problem. I have never unwrapped a shadow cube map in real-time like this to see what it is supposed to look like, but it does not look right to me. The penguin should be rotated when it produces depth on the side faces. Can you turn off face culling and verify that when the penguin is at the light's origin, it produces depth in all 6 faces?

Comment: It does: http://youtu.be/xjKe14Rf26w I've also updated my initial post with some information about how I'm drawing to the shadow cubemap. The light position is currently at the world origin (0,0,0), so that shouldn't be affecting anything for now anyway.

Comment: You accidentally edited my answer. But the code you edited had 2 issues, you are writing the window-space Z value to a color buffer (unnecessary assuming you are using a depth attachment) and it also does not show the important part where you generate the modelview matrix for each of the 6 cubemap faces. That is what I meant when I asked you to show how the cubemap was generated.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the requested information to my post.

Comment: Immediately, I notice your use of `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` for the `S` and `T` (**X** and **Y**) directions in your cube map. The default border color is **0.0** (to put this another way, it behaves as if there is something 0 units away in the depth buffer), so this may explain the unusual behavior where only lighting in the Z direction works. You should use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for all 3 directions. I will take a closer look at the rest of it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why, but I swapped from my laptop to my home PC and ever since swapping some of the view matrices for the light it works as it's supposed to: http://youtu.be/nrCvIOICvPs Still broken on my laptop, but I'm sure I'll be able to figure that one out. Thanks a lot for your assistance! I'll credit you the bounty as soon as the system lets me.